# drag and drop when droppable stop change image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm new in jquery.. I want when my icons drag and drop inside the droppable the hover image stop changing image when it is dropped inside.. I'm not sure how to do it.. Now  whenever I hover and move out it's changing image.. I wanted when there is icons inside droppable the hover and out is disable only when there is no icons inside droppable the hover and out image works again..

**jsFiddle**

```
https://jsfiddle.net/xInfinityMing/tsc0no9g/
```

**Java:**

```
$(function() {
$("#dragIcons img").draggable({
revert: "invalid",
refreshPositions: true,
drag: function(event, ui) {
  ui.helper.removeClass("end-draggable");
  ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
  ui.helper.addClass("end-draggable");
  ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
}
});
$("#briefcase-full").droppable({
  over: function(event, ui) {
  $(this).parent().css('background-image','url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/yosemite-flat/512/Folder-icon.png")');
  },
  out: function(event, ui) {
  $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snow_sabre_silver/512/folder_web_upload.png")');
  },
  drop: function(event, ui) {
  $(this).parent().css('background-image','url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/yosemite-flat/512/Folder-icon.png")');
  if ($("#briefcase").length == 0) {
    $("#briefcase-droppable").html("");
    }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      $("#briefcase-droppable").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I have difficulty understanding your question. Could you tell us what you want?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/tsc0no9g/1/

Comment: Yes something like that! thanks.. but when there is no icon inside droppable will the hover works??

Comment: Yes...you can see that case when you try to drag and drop the first time. When you try to drag and drop the first time, there is no icon inside..so hover and out works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding a simple check to find if the `briefcase-droppable` container has any icons added already using `if(!($("#briefcase-droppable").find(".ui-draggable").length))`.

Here is a simple working code

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dragIcons img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    refreshPositions: true,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.removeClass("end-draggable");
      ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass("end-draggable");
      ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
    }
  });
  $("#briefcase-full").droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
      if (!($("#briefcase-droppable").find(".ui-draggable").length)) {
        $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/yosemite-flat/512/Folder-icon.png")');
      }
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
      if (!($("#briefcase-droppable").find(".ui-draggable").length)) {

        $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snow_sabre_silver/512/folder_web_upload.png")');
      }

    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/yosemite-flat/512/Folder-icon.png")');
      if ($("#briefcase").length == 0) {
        $("#briefcase-droppable").html("");
      }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      $("#briefcase-droppable").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1.0;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: none !important;
  animation: pulse 0.4s alternate infinite;
}
.end-draggable {
  animation: 0;
}
.dropped {
  position: static !important;
  transition: none !important;
  animation: 0;
}
#dragIcons {
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#briefcase {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mcdo-design/smooth-leopard/256/Upload-Folder-Blue-icon.png");
  background-position: background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}
#briefcase-open {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  background: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snow_sabre_silver/512/folder_web_upload.png");
  background-position: background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}
#briefcase-droppable {
  border-style: solid;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
@keyframes pulse {
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
#briefcase-full {
  border-style: solid;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="dragIcons">
  <img width="100px" height="100px" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/256/MS_Office_Upload_Center.png">
  <img width="100px" height="100px" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/256/MS_Office_Upload_Center.png">
  <img width="100px" height="100px" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/256/MS_Office_Upload_Center.png">
  <img width="100px" height="100px" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/256/MS_Office_Upload_Center.png">
</div>
<div id="briefcase">
  <div id="briefcase-full">
  </div>
  <div id="briefcase-droppable">
  </div>
</div>
```